# Consider scaling on Rails, would you write hand coded SQL? Use Sequel gem?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaling, sequel

If I wanted to scale a Rails application by distributing its database on a different machine based on its authorization rules (location and user roles). So any resource attributed to that location would be sitting in a database dedicated to that location.

Should I get down to basic SQL writing, use something like Sequel gem or keep the niceness and *magic* of ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that raw SQL execution speed is more than execution of the ActiveRecord's nice magical queries. However, if you talk about scaling then there comes this question of how well would the queries be manageable when the application really grows large.

By far, a lot of complicated database operations can be managed well by caching, and proper indexing and proper eager-loading. In some cases MySQL views also help to improve performance, and Rails treats MySQL views fairly. After this, if one is able to corner out the really slow queries, then it might be worth it to convert them to raw SQL and save some time. Also,  Rails offer caching of the database queries. MySQL also has a [caching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html) mechanism. Before executing raw SQL directly I would make sure these options (actually many more like avoiding unnecessary joins, as a join operation is resource intensive) are not able to give me what I am looking for. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are partitioning your database, which Sequel has built-in support for (http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/sharding_rdoc.html).  I recommend using Sequel, but as the lead developer, I'm biased.